# How to make OAuth implicit flow work with admin-on-rest?

Tags: admin-on-rest

With OAuth implicit flow when we authenticate the SPA gets a redirect which has the access_token and id_token as hash  fragment, but this doesn't work with the hash-based routing of admin-on-rest. Is there a way to get the hash fragments other than creating a custom Admin component with Browser router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass your own instance of `history` to the admin component (not documented yet: see the [code](https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/blob/master/src/Admin.js#L30). By default its the `hashHistory`. See history [documentation](https://github.com/reacttraining/history#usage) for other options.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom menu.

https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Admin.html#menu

You can use the React Router Link element which accepts objects and set hash routes.

```
<MenuItem key={"cc"} containerElement={<Link to={ linkObj } />} primaryText="All Approved Tales" onTouchTap={onMenuTap} />
```